# Printing Index of an associative array

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm trying to print keys of an associative array for the simple logic shown below

```
declare
  type std_marks_arr is table of number(10)
        index by BINARY_INTEGER;--
  std_marks std_marks_arr;
  cursor std_id is select student_code from student_master; 
begin
    for i in std_id
    loop
        select sum(marks) into std_marks(i.student_code) from student_marks
        where student_code=i.student_code;
    end loop;
    for i in std_marks.first..std_marks.last
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line(rpad(std_marks(i).key,10,' ')||rpad(std_marks(i),10,' '));
    end loop;
end;`
```

Its giving an error like 
`'Invalid reference to variable 'NUMBER'` in line where i used `key`

I Know that it can be done by other means but i have to know how can i print index in this situation.

Comment: I assume `student_code` is a numeric column.

Comment: sorry for that `student_code ` it should not come their. this is currect one though the error remains same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `std_marks` has an associative array type as its type, which has no attribute `key` (and indeed, has no attributes - it's just an array of values).

In your code, `i` is the index, which will be a simple number, so you would just use this:

```
for i in std_marks.first..std_marks.last
loop
    dbms_output.put_line(rpad(i,10,
    ' ')||rpad(std_marks(i),10,' '));
end loop
```

You have a few other issues in your code, however, that will stop it compiling (e.g. missing semicolon) and running (e.g. unless your student codes form a series with no gaps in numeric sequence, your code will raise NO_DATA_FOUND because your loop tries to access all array elements from the First index value to the Last index value, including gaps).